# Configure Eclipse with websphere liberty tools with Java EE 7 javadoc integration

Tags: eclipse, websphere-liberty, ibm-wdt

I'm using eclipse Neon and WebSphere liberty as a JEE 7 application server.
how can I get Java EE 7 documentation displayed when I hit ctrl space.
I know the standar way is to attach sources, but what is the jar to select since liberty is my runtime environement that provides the JEE 7 libraries.

Comment: PS: I'm not using maven, I'm working with a dynamic web project.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by expanding the ***Libraries/<Liberty runtime name>*** under the dynamic web project on the *Project Explorer* view. By default, the *<Liberty runtime name>* is *WebSphere Application Server Liberty*. Then, add the Java EE documentation URL to all the jars that starts with ***com.ibm.ws.javaee***, e.g. com.ibm.ws.javaee.servlet.3.1_1.0.14.jar.

To add the javadoc URL to a specific jar, you can right click on the jar entry and select Properties. Then, you can add the javadoc URL on the Javadoc Location section.